# How to disable form submit when inputs are empty in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a form and I want to disable form submit when input fields are empty. I want to show an error when user clicks on submit button where the input fields are empty. I don't want to show error by default.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/Registratonvalidation.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', []).controller("numOnlyRegex", function ($scope)
            {
                $scope.numOnlyRegex = /^\d{1,6}$/;
            });
        </script>
        <!--<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/numOnlyRegex.js"></script>-->
        <title>Registration Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h2 class="text-muted">Registration form</h2>
                                <!--onSubmit="return validate()"-->
                                <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="numOnlyRegex">
                                    <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" novalidate >
                                        First name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="uname" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span><br/>
                                        Last name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="lname" ng-model="lname" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-]{3,20}/" required placeholder="Last Name"/>
                                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.lname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span><br/>
                                        <p>Password:
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="pwd" required placeholder="Password"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pwd.$error.minlength">password cannot be less than 3 letters</span><br/>
                                            Confirm Password:<input type="password" class="form-control input-sm glyphicon glyphicon-ok" name="pwd2" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="pwd2" required placeholder="Confirm Password"/><br/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pwd2.$error.minlength">password cannot be less than 3 letters</span><br/>
                                            Gender: <input type="radio" name="female" ng-model="color" value="female" ng-required="!color"/>Female <input type="radio" name="male" ng-model="color" value="male" ng-required="!color"/>Male <br/><br/>
                                            Mobile:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="mobile" ng-pattern="/^[7-9][0-9]{1,9}$/" ng-model="mobile" required placeholder="Mobile"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.mobile.$error.pattern">Please enter a valid mobile number</span><br/>
                                            Email:<input type="email" class="form-control input-sm" name="email" ng-pattern="/\S+@\S+\.\S+/" ng-model="email" required placeholder="Email"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.pattern">Invalid email address</span><br/>
                                            Address:<textarea class="form-control input-sm" name="address" ng-model="address" required placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.address.$error.require==true">Address cannot be empty</span><br/>
                                            Street:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="street" ng-model="street" required placeholder="Street"/>
                                            Area:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="area" ng-model="area" required placeholder="Area"/>

                                            City:   <select name="city" class="form-control" ng-model="city" required>
                                                <option value="hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
                                                <option value="secunderabad">Secunderabad</option>
                                                <option value="delhi">Delhi</option>
                                                <option value="mumbai">Mumbai</option>
                                            </select><br/>
                                            State: <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="state" ng-model="state" required placeholder="State"/>
                                            Country: <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="country" ng-model="country" required placeholder="Country"/>
                                            Pin:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" ng-pattern="numOnlyRegex" name="pin" ng-model="pin" required placeholder="Pin"/>
                                            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.pin.$error.pattern">Only six-digit number is allowed</span>
                                            <input type="Submit" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
                                            <!--ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"-->
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use required field of HTML ..

Comment: I have already used required field and its not stoping user from submitting the form when input fields are empty

Comment: @ShubhamNigam required option is not working on drop down select. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='submit' ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">
```

Comment: `required` option is not working on drop down select. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `novalidate` and `ng-disabled` on form and already having `required` option of html fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.cityArray= ["hyderabad","secunderabad","delhi","mumbai"];  

<select ng-model = "city" ng-options="city for city in cityArray" name='city'>
</select>
```

Comment: drop down is empty when I try this way

Comment: how do I make it `required`. I tried `<select ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in cityArray" name='city' required>` but not luck

Comment: Also I have a new problem now. Removing `ng-disabled` gave the desired feature for checking empty fields on submit but now incorrect entry is not working as user is able to submit the form with incorrect entries as button is not disabled